conductors of representations coming from jacobians of curves
Let $C$ be a curve defined over $\mathbb{Q}$, and we denote by $J:=Jac(C)$ its Jacobian.
For a prime $l$, we define by $V_l(J)=T_l(J)\otimes \mathbb{Q}_l$. There is a natural action of the absolute Galois group $G_{\mathbb{Q}}$ on $V_l$ which gives rise to an $l$-adic Galois representation described as
$$\rho_{J,l}: G_{\mathbb{Q}} \to Aut_{\mathbb{Q}_l}(V_l).$$
I am confused about the notion of the conductor. When people talk about the conductor of $J/\mathbb{Q}$, do they mean the Artin conductor of the $l$-adic representation $\rho_{J,l}$ for some $l$? If not how are the two conductors (of $J/\mathbb{Q}$ and the Artin conductor of $\rho_{J,l}$) related?

You can see immediately that it can't just be the Artin conductor: if $J$ has bad reduction at $\ell$, then $\ell$ should divide the conductor, but, by definition, the Artin conductor is prime to $\ell$. The correct notion should be the Artin conductor multiplied by the contribution from $\ell$, which can be defined using $p$-adic Hodge theory. But when $J$ has good reduction at $\ell$, this contribution is just $1$, so the conductor is just the Artin conductor....

.... as for whether it equals the conductor of $J$: how are you defining the conductor of $J$? For me, the conductor of $J$ is defined to be the conductor of $\rho_{J, \ell}$. For example, even when $J$ is an elliptic curve, the seemingly ad hoc definition of the conductor at primes above $2$ and $3$ is to ensure that the conductor matches the conductor of the Tate module.

@Mathmo123  Thanks for the prompt response, I agree my question is slightly wrongly posed. My confusion was precisely about the definition of the conductor of $J$, as I came across different sources that mention it but do not define it. If I understand your answer correctly, in order to define the conductor of $J$, I should first look for a prime of good reduction $l$, and then compute the Artin conductor of the $l$-adic representation $\rho_{J,l}$, is that correct?

That definition works! Of course, there’s work required to show that it’s well defined. (I.e. that it does not depend on $\ell$). I believe the reference is Serre Tate’s paper where they define the Neron Ogg Shafarevich condition, but I may be wrong
